# Solr add field to schema using curl

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

```
A:\DOS> curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"timestamp","type":"date","indexed":true,"stored":true,\
"default":NOW,"multiValued":false}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/testt/schema
{
  "reponseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
   "errors":"no stream"}
```

I am trying to add a 'timestamp' field to solr and this is the error which I am getting. Can anyone help me figure out where I am wrong in this?

Comment: [Please don't post code and error messages as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

There may have two problem

## &commit=true

- At the end of URL commit parameter was not added.

## schema.xml

- Schema not contain field you wanted to set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your curl command. Because if you try it differently it works

```
curl -d '@timestamp.json' -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' http://localhost:8983/solr/testt/schema
```

and create the `timestamp.json` file

```
{ 
"add-field":{"name":"timestamp","type":"date","indexed":true,"stored":true,"default":NOW,"multiValued":false}
}
```